# Hue, colorbar, or scatterplot colors do not match in seaborn.scatterplot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

Using [an example from another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60721598/how-to-set-the-hue-range-for-a-numeric-variable-using-a-colored-bubble-plot-in-s), I'm adding a color bar to a scatter plot. The idea is that both dot hue, and colorbar hue, should conform to the maximum and minimum possible, so that the colorbar can reflect the range of values in the hue:

```
x= [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 200]
y= [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 200]
z= [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 255]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(x, y, z)), columns =['x', 'y', 'z']) 


colormap=matplotlib.cm.viridis
#A continuous color bar needs to be added independently
norm = plt.Normalize(df.z.min(), df.z.max())
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=colormap, norm=norm)
sm.set_array([])

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (10,8), dpi=300)
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1) 
sb.scatterplot(x="x", y="y",
                 hue="z", 
                 hue_norm=(0,255),
                 data=df,
                 palette=colormap,
                 ax=ax
                 )
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0., title='hue from sb.scatterplot')
ax.figure.colorbar(sm).set_label('hue from sm')

plt.xlim(0,255)
plt.ylim(0,255)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note how the hue from the scatterplot, even with `hue_norm`, ranges up to 300. In turn, the hue from the `colorbar` ranges from `0` to `255`. From experimenting with values in `hue_norm`, it seems that matplotlib always rounds it off so that you have a "good" (even?) number of intervals.

My questions are:

1. Is which one is showing an incorrect range: the scatterplot, the scatterplot legend, or the colorbar? And how to correct it?
2. How could you retrieve min and max hue from the scatterplot (in this case 0 and 300, respectively), in order to set them as maximum and minimum of the `colorbar`?

Comment: I feel that my title is awful, so if anyone has a better suggestion for it please feel free to edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you really need to use seaborn's `scatterplot()`. Using a numerical `hue` is always quite messy.

The following code is much simpler and yields an unambiguous output

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
g = ax.scatter(df['x'],df['y'], c=df['z'], cmap=colormap)
fig.colorbar(g)
```

[image]

Comment: ahahah well, that's a fair point indeed! I will see if I can get away with matplotlib then :)